# Get specific column from csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

I'm new in python programming and i have a question about reading from csv file.
What am I trying to do is to split in 2 my csv file and save in two list.
So form my next csv file:

```
    5.1,3.5,1.5,0.2,setosa
    4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,setosa
    4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,setosa
```

I need my lists to look like:

```
firstList = [ [5.1, 3.5, 1.5, 0.2], [4.9, 3.0, 1.4, 0.2], [4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2] ]
secondList = ['setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa']
```

I tried different time, but my closest result is the next one:

```
firstList = []
secondList = []

with open('file.csv') as file:
    fileReader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
    for row in fileReader:
        firstList.append(row)
        secondList.append(row[4])
```

And the output for this one is:

```
firstList = [ ['5.1', '3.5', '1.5', '0.2', 'setosa'], ['4.9', '3.0', '1.4', '0.2', 'setosa'], ['4.6', '3.1', '1.5', '0.2', 'setosa'] ]
secondList = ['setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa']
```

I just want to get rid of string 'setosa' from my firstList and also convert everything else into int
Any help would be grateful. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a sublist of the first three cells in the row then build floats as you create a new list from them.

```
firstList = []
secondList = []

with open('file.csv') as file:
    fileReader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
    for row in fileReader:
        firstList.append([float(cell) for cell in row[:3]])
        secondList.append(row[4])
```